# Detect CCSprite touch in small distance between them

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have some small sprites (width/height) in a `CCLayer` and i want to detect which of them is touched. I use the following code.

```
- (BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchLocation = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:touch];

    CGRect rect = sprite.boundingBox;

    // i am doing this because of the small size of the sprites, 
    // so it would be more easy to detect if a sprite is taped and then move it.
    if (rect.size.width > rect.size.height) {
        rect.size.width *= 2.5;
        rect.size.height *= 5;
        rect.origin.y -= rect.size.height / 2;

    } else {
        rect.size.width *= 5;
        rect.size.height *= 2.5;
        rect.origin.x -= rect.size.width / 2;
    }

    CCSprite *s = nil;
    for (CCSprite *sprite in [self children]) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(rect, touchPoint)) {
            s = sprite;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (s != nil) {
        // do something here
    }

    return YES;
}
```

All works fine except when two sprites is very close (not overlap) to each other. Then because of the small distance between them, the wrong sprite is detected.

Any idea how could i correct it?

Comment: do the sprite images have transparent borders? Because those borders are also within the boundingbox.

Comment: no they don't. I think that the problem is on how i resize the rect to make it easier to detect the sprite. But if don't do it it is very difficult to detect it because of th small size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to enlarge the rects keeping their center where it originally is, you should use:

```
    rect.origin.y -= (rectFinalHeight - rectOriginalHeight) / 2;
```

and

```
    rect.origin.y -= (rectFinalWidth - rectOriginalWidth) / 2;
```

which would be:

```
if (rect.size.width > rect.size.height) {
    rect.size.width *= 2.5;
    rect.size.height *= 5;
    rect.origin.y -= rect.size.height * 4 / 2;

} else {
    rect.size.width *= 5;
    rect.size.height *= 2.5;
    rect.origin.x -= rect.size.width * 4 / 2;
}
```

IMO, you should adjust the rect origin along both axis in both cases (and not only in one case along the x axis and in the other along the y axis), otherwise your rect will not be centered. But you understand better what you are trying to do, here...

Comment: The first part of the answer is correct. I try it first *4 as you suggest but it didn't worked. Then i try subtract original width/height and worked just fine. Thank you